# Preserve the position of User Forms VBA

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I'd like to preserve the position of a number of forms in the centre of the application, forms will be different sizes so below FormTop/FormLeft snippet can't be run again and again with the same effect. To do this I'm setting a public variable with the form's .top and .left values.

I get an error "Object Doesn't support this property or method", which seems odd as I was under the impression that the equation to make FormLeft would evaluate to a double data type. Both the lines work fine in the second section of code, what am I doing wrong?

```
Public FormTop As Double
Public FormLeft As Double

sub main()
    CentreForm UserForm2
end sub

Sub CentreForm(UForm As UserForm)
    With UForm
        If FormTop = 0 And FormLeft = 0 Then
'*********Errors appear on the below two lines******************
            FormLeft = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
            FormTop = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
            Debug.Print FormLeft, FormTop
        End If
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = FormLeft
        .Top = FormTop
    End With
End Sub

sub IWork()
With UserForm2
    .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
    .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
end with
end sub
```

Comment: which line produces error??

Comment: Oops, the lines where FormLeft and FormTop both product the error, I will update now...

Comment: how do you call `CentreForm procedure`??

Comment: generally speaking, it seems that you pass `UserForm2` to `CentreForm` in the wrong way. check it please...

Comment: @KazimierzJawor, Excellent, thankyou. I set the form to an object variable and passed it to the function, the points are yours if you want to post an answer to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't solve your problem based on comment suggestion please change this line:

```
Sub CentreForm(UForm As UserForm)
```

into

```
Sub CentreForm(UForm As Object)
```